# Authentication routes of adminLTE in laravel

Tags: laravel, adminlte

New to laravel framework here. I am trying to integrate the forms of adminLTE into my laravel project but it is confusing especially checking out the auth folder and also the root folder (adminlte.php). Need help!

```
`@section('body')
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-logo">
                <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.dashboard_url', 'home')) }}">{!! config('adminlte.logo', '<b>Admin</b>LTE') !!}</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.login-logo -->
            <div class="login-box-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.login_message') }}</p>
                <form action="{{ url(config('adminlte.login_url', 'login')) }}" method="post">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}"
                               placeholder="{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.email') }}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.password') }}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> {{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.remember_me') }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-flat"><a href="{{ url('adminlte.login') }}">{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.sign_in') }}</a>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="auth-links">
                    <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.password_reset_url', 'password/reset')) }}"
                       class="text-center"
                    >**{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.i_forgot_my_password')** }}</a>
                    <br>
                    @if (config('adminlte.register_url', 'register'))
                        <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.register_url', 'register')) }}"
                           class="text-center"
                        >{{ **trans('adminlte::adminlte.register_a_new_membership') }}**</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.login-box-body -->
        </div><!-- /.login-box -->
    @stop`
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question or describe a problem that you're having!

Comment: `trans('adminlte::adminlte.register_a_new_membership') }}`. this sample blaze template, i tried to check it in the root folder of adminLTE to make some edit but, i haven't found it.

Comment: Have you published the assets? Views should be here `resources/views/vendor/adminlte` and language files here `resources/lang/vendor/adminlte_lang`. Please clarify what you are looking to do.